# PayPal IPN php always INVALID

Tags: php, paypal

I've made an attempt at writing a small PayPal IPN handler however I'm always getting 'INVALID' when using the IPN simulator https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator . I'm not sure what about the URL I'm sending back isn't right. I have looked at some Gists for this topic but they all seem a little long winded. Their docs on this are here https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/#protocol_and_arch and I think that I have followed all the steps for the protocol.
Any help is appreciated

```
<?php

    /**
     * Validates a PayPal IPN notification
     * @param  array $req The $_POST variable for the request
     * @return String     Returns the validity: 'VALID' or 'INVALID'
     */
    function verifyPayPalIPN($req) {

        // Base URL for the php validation
        $baseURL = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate';

        // Loop through the POST parameters to 
        // create the validaton URL
        $postVars = '';
        foreach ($req as $key => $value) {
            $postVars .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
        }

        // Strip the last & off of the URL
        $postVars        = substr($postVars, 0, -1);

        // Send the request to PayPal to confirm 
        // whether the request to the script is 
        // from PayPal
        $requestValidity = system("curl --data '$postVars' $baseURL");

        return $requestValidity;
    }
    file_put_contents('/tmp/result.txt', verifyPayPalIPN($_POST));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`cmd=_notify-validate` should be part of your postVars string

```
$baseURL = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

// Loop through the POST parameters to 
// create the validaton URL
$postVars = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($req as $key => $value) {
    $postVars .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
}
```

The code that I have used in the past is this:

```
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ("ssl://www.paypal.com", 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$fp) {
    // HTTP ERROR
} else {

    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

        } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {

        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Note the port no. 443 also

Comment: Have tried this method and I'm still getting INVALID. Would I have to do an actual purchase to get this to say VALID or would the IPN simulator send 'VERIFIED' requests to the listener?

Answer (score 0):

firstly, check if your paying enviroment and validating enviroment is the same (both `sandbox` or both `production`), if they are not, say your customer paid their order in an `production` enviroment, but then your PHP code trying to request a `sandbox` enviroment end point to verify the IPN request, then it will always end as INVALIDE